# weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, oracle, deployment, weblogic

java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:193)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:532)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1486)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:944)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:735)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3182)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\newdispute.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\DisputeManager\beadep\newdms\DisputeManager\split_src\DisputeCommons.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at weblogic.j2eeclient.AppClientModule.setupClassFinder(AppClientModule.java:344)
    at weblogic.j2eeclient.AppClientModule.init(AppClientModule.java:235)
    at weblogic.j2eeclient.AppClientModule.init(AppClientModule.java:128)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:311)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:532)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:558)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:727)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:239)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:241)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:794)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1340)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:267)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\newdispute.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\DisputeManager\beadep\newdms\DisputeManager\split_src\DisputeCommons.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

```
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.JarClassFinder.<init>(JarClassFinder.java:42)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.JarClassFinder.<init>(JarClassFinder.java:29)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.JarClassFinder.<init>(JarClassFinder.java:25)
at weblogic.j2eeclient.AppClientModule.setupClassFinder(AppClientModule.java:342)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\newdispute.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\DisputeManager\beadep\newdms\DisputeManager\split_src\DisputeCommons.jar - obviously the given file is not there.

Comment: The file is there at the said location

Comment: If the file is there, does WebLogic also have access to it?